# Recover updated data on a table

Tags: sql-server

I need to recover an update on a column that I did yesterday on SQL Server 2014, is there a way to get the old data? Can I get it without doing a full restore ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get it withput doing a full restore ?

No.  Restore from a backup to a new database and copy the data you want.

Comment: The data may be in the log file, and there are some third-party tools to read from it.  But nothing supported or out-of-the-box.

Comment: If you have a backup from before the problem update, you can restore to a different database and extract the data before the update.